# what are the units of pressure shown by pointer location in android?

Tags: android, android-service, android-developer-api

while using pointer location(available in developer options) in android it shows some values of pressure and size . what are the units of size and pressure . 
Somewhere I read that it is the normalized pressure , but normalized with reference to what .. it should also have some units right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no units. Pressure is just a floating point ranging from 0 to 1.

> The pressure generally ranges from 0 (no pressure at all) to 1 (normal pressure), although values higher than 1 may be generated depending on the calibration of the input device.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.PointerCoords.html#pressure